# Global try-catch for loading pages in asp.net (vb in this case)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

What I got:

- `SecureBasePage.vb` (to be inherited by pages that require to login)
- `Default.aspx` which inherits `SecureBasePage`

What should be the case: client requests `Default.aspx` but gets redirected to login because he isn't logged in.

`SecureBasePage.vb` has this constructor

```
Public Sub ()
        If userIsAuthenticated Then

        Else
            Throw New LoginException()
        End If

End Sub
```

This results in a exception `LoginException`. Now I want to let it being catched by a somehow global exception handler which kicks the client to `login.aspx`.

I know there is a function `Application_Error()` in `Global.asax` but in my opinion this isn't an exception handler as it only takes the `Server.GetLastError()` and doesn't catch the exception. So more likely this function is to allow a developer to send an email about the unhandled exception. I'd call this a 'global *unhandled exception* handler' instead of an '*global exception handler*'.

Is there anything I can kinda try-catch to catch the constructors exception throwing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all pages requiring login will inherit from the `SecureBasePage` class, it would probably make the most sense to implement your logic there. Just override one of the page methods like `OnLoad` or `OnPreLoad` to handle the redirection.

I wouldn't advise depending on the `global.asax` to handle the errors, so your base class is probably the most appropriate place.

**EDIT**

As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't use exceptions to control the flow of logic. Unless the exception itself contains useful logging information, it's probably more costly than beneficial, especially for logic that's going to be used on nearly every request.

This article offers some useful advice on the topic:

- [Best Practices of Exception Management](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akrao/ExceptionManagement11142005020738AM/ExceptionManagement.aspx)

Comment: Yes but the reason why I want to do it globally, is because I want to make my own exceptions globally too. That way its not bound to page but global

Comment: If all of the pages requiring this logic are inheriting from `SecureBasePage`, then it's already global by way of inheritance. Also, generating your own exceptions is not a good approach; custom exceptions should be reserved for design flaws or limitations.

Comment: Oke well maybe it's better to do it in `SecureBasePage`, but can you give me an article or something that explains the 'best practice' use of custom exceptions and the why of not using it in this way, as I need to explain this to my supervisor. He kinda insists on using exceptions as such.

Comment: You're using the exception in this case to control the flow of logic, which is more costly than beneficial. Unless you're going to log specific information about the exception, it would be more efficient to use a simple condition. Throwing and handling exceptions can be expensive, and thus should be implemented with consideration. This article for more details: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akrao/ExceptionManagement11142005020738AM/ExceptionManagement.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment :). It's very useful. About the meaning of `Application_Error()`, is it true what I stated in my question?